# Setting long environmental variables in nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku, firebase, environment-variables

On a Node server that will be deployed to heroku, I have to load a long private key from the environmental variables. When I declare my environmental variable in a .env file in the traditional method (key=value, with no linebreaks if value is long), run it locally (through 'heroku local') and console.log the loaded environmental variable value, the console shows it has been split into several lines (but not around the '\n' character).

Loading the string from environmental variable:

[image: Env variable loading]

Loading the string when it's hardcoded into the server and console logging shows:

[image]

I switched to foreman to load environmental variables and used the JSON syntax to get it working. My question is, on the traditional method, why does the console show the string is split up?

Loading the long value as this value is required for Firebase 3 SDK initialisation, as Heroku does not allow you to load the private key file itself.

Comment: It looks like one of your terminals is set to wrap lines, while the other one isn't. I recommend searching in that direction, because it is unlikely this has much to do with the code that logs.

Comment: Thanks. That output has been taken from the same terminal. From my server, I console.log the loaded environmental variable and the hardcoded string, just to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For local development, the solution is to start the server using [Node-Foreman](https://github.com/strongloop/node-foreman) and load the environmental variables from the .env file through the node-foreman utility. Use the JSON format for the environmental variables (*not* the key=value format). The JSON usage is described in the documentation.